# Healthy cloudsql configuration

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was interested to hear people's thoughts and implementation on the healthiest configuration for cloudsql instances.

I have cloudsql instance memory utilisation around 30-40% and cpu usage around 3-8%.

Was just wondering what everyone else perceives as a healthy config and why